# Select last message with each user

Tags: sqlite, select, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite table in android with messages like this:

```
@primarykey
long id;
String from;
String to;
long timestamp;
String body;
```

In this table are all messages between me and other users in one:one chat.
I need a select which will return last message between me and each user. 
I know how to get all distinct from and to addresses, merge them and select last message for each individually, but I need better approach - t do it in one step

```
    @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH)
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT `from`, `to` FROM Message")
    LiveData<List<ChatHelper>> getDinstinctChats();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Message where `from` LIKE :address OR `to` LIKE :address ORDER BY `timestamp` LIMIT 1")
    LiveData<List<ChatMessage>> getLastMessageWith(String address);
```

There are similar problems described on the stackoverflow, but I did not found anything really working.

Answer (score 0):

First, get all message between me and other users, and reorder the columns so that the other user is always in a fixed column:

```
SELECT id, `from` AS other, timestamp, body
FROM Message
WHERE `to` LIKE :address
UNION ALL
SELECT id, `to`   AS other, timestamp, body
FROM Message
WHERE `from` LIKE :address;
```

Then group by the "other" column to get one result row per user:

```
SELECT *, max(timestamp)
FROM (SELECT id, `from` AS other, timestamp, body
      FROM Message
      WHERE `to` LIKE :address
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, `to`   AS other, timestamp, body
      FROM Message
      WHERE `from` LIKE :address)
GROUP BY other;
```